# Embed popular videos from YouTube channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, embed, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

How to embed **Popular videos** (*Most Viewed*) from YouTube channel into a blog using **YouTube IFrame API**?

According to documentation valid `listType` parameter values are `playlist`, `search`, and `user_uploads`. Can't find something for listing popular videos.

Answer (score 0):

You can use chart parameter:

> The chart parameter identifies the chart that you want to retrieve.
>   Acceptable values are:
>
> - **mostPopular** – Return the most popular videos for the specified [content region](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#regionCode) and [video category](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#videoCategoryId).

Sample Snippet:

```
// Sample js code for videos.list

// See full sample for buildApiRequest() code, which is not 
// specific to a particular youtube or youtube method.

buildApiRequest('GET',
                '/youtube/v3/videos',
                {'chart': 'mostPopular',
                 'regionCode': 'US',
                 'part': 'snippet,contentDetails,statistics',
                 'videoCategoryId': ''});
```

Hope this helps.

## [UPDATE]

You can do [search->list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) with specifying the **`channelId`** and order = **`viewcount`**.

> The **`order`** parameter specifies the method that will be used to order resources in the API response. The default value is **`relevance`**.
>
> Acceptable values are:
>
> - **date** – Resources are sorted in reverse chronological order based on the date they were created.
> - **rating** – Resources are sorted from highest to lowest rating.
> - **relevance** – Resources are sorted based on their relevance to the search query. This is the default value for this parameter.
> - **title** – Resources are sorted alphabetically by title.
> - **videoCount** – Channels are sorted in descending order of their number of uploaded videos.
> - **viewCount** – Resources are sorted from highest to lowest number of views. For live broadcasts, videos are sorted by number of concurrent viewers while the broadcasts are ongoing.

Comment: I meant the most viewed videos on a channel.

Comment: How can I use it with YouTube IFrame API? @Mr.Rebot

Comment: You can get the videoID using the search.list(), then play it using the youtube iframe API

Comment: If you don't mind, can you share an example code? I'm a noob with these things.@Mr.Rebot

Answer (score 0):

Well, first how do you define **popular videos**? For instance if you decide popular videos are the ones with the most views, you can do a search on the channel and order the results by viewCount.

Comment: Yes, I meant most viewed videos. Can you share the code with viewCount? I'm a beginner.